# Make two columns from one column covering all combinations

Tags: r, combinatorics

This appears to be a simple question but is causing me a lot of headache (it's not homework, but a sticking point in real research)

I have a single list with 2266 levels. The list looks somewhat like this:

```
[1] ~/folder1/folder1/a.bin
[2] ~/folder1/folder1/b.bin
[3] ~/folder1/folder1/c.bin
[4] ~/folder1/folder2/a.bin
[5] ~/folder1/folder2/b.bin
[6] ~/folder1/folder2/c.bin
```

To explain: the list is filenames of binary files that I am reading in using the `readBin` function. I want to compare every row with every other row, so what I want are **two columns which contain all unique combinations in them, derived from my single column**.

`(choose 2266,2)` tells me that there are 2566245 combinations of our single column into two.

`[expand.grid()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/expand.grid.html) appears to get me half way there. But there are four times as many combinations as I require: I get two rows each 5132490. This means that there are duplications: 1 + 2 and 2 + 1 are the same thing for my purpose.

`expand.grid.df` with `unique=TRUE` also doesn't seem to help.

My last idea was md5 hashing each of the 5 million rows and trying to detect duplicates that way.

I am looking for some way of making two lists which cover the 2566245 combinations of my list. Alternatively some way of removing all the duplicates. *I guess I am not absolutely wedded to using R and have investigated awk or sed to do the same thing. No success yet though.*

Comment: Did you try `combn(all_files, 2)`?

Comment: I tried combn too. I can try again...

Comment: `combn(all_files, 2)` doesn't work (not even close).

Comment: could you elaborate `doesn't work`?

Comment: how many combinations do you get on just the 6 files you've shown above?

Comment: I just get a screen full of garbage: `[,2566004] [,2566005] [,2566006] [,2566007] [,2566008] [,2566009]`

Comment: @Roul `combn(x,m) has choose(length(x), m)` terms , so it should work.

Comment: @Rsoul, I suspect you're using it wrong. Can you *edit your post* with `dput(head(your_data))`?

Comment: They are not garbage, they are the corresponding indices I think. Please post the `dput` output.

Comment: @Arun by garbage I mean I can't use it for purposes. I am testing combn again now. As for dput, I will have to depersonalise it first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `combn` looking like `expand.grid`, using @Arun data,

```
v <- c("~/folder1/folder1/a.bin", 
       "~/folder1/folder1/b.bin", 
       "~/folder1/folder1/c.bin", 
       "~/folder1/folder2/a.bin", 
       "~/folder1/folder2/b.bin", 
       "~/folder1/folder2/c.bin")
do.call(rbind,combn(v,2,simplify=F))

    [,1]                      [,2]                     
 [1,] "~/folder1/folder1/a.bin" "~/folder1/folder1/b.bin"
 [2,] "~/folder1/folder1/a.bin" "~/folder1/folder1/c.bin"
 [3,] "~/folder1/folder1/a.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/a.bin"
 [4,] "~/folder1/folder1/a.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/b.bin"
 [5,] "~/folder1/folder1/a.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/c.bin"
 [6,] "~/folder1/folder1/b.bin" "~/folder1/folder1/c.bin"
 [7,] "~/folder1/folder1/b.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/a.bin"
 [8,] "~/folder1/folder1/b.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/b.bin"
 [9,] "~/folder1/folder1/b.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/c.bin"
[10,] "~/folder1/folder1/c.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/a.bin"
[11,] "~/folder1/folder1/c.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/b.bin"
[12,] "~/folder1/folder1/c.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/c.bin"
[13,] "~/folder1/folder2/a.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/b.bin"
[14,] "~/folder1/folder2/a.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/c.bin"
[15,] "~/folder1/folder2/b.bin" "~/folder1/folder2/c.bin"
```

**EDIT**

I think that the path format over complicte the problem. If we use for example letters in place of file names, we get :

```
do.call(rbind,combn(letters[1:4],2,simplify=F))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "a"  "c" 
[3,] "a"  "d" 
[4,] "b"  "c" 
[5,] "b"  "d" 
[6,] "c"  "d"
```

So As you see there is no duplictated.

Comment: Looks good with a the first 6 of my filenames. Just testing it with all of them. Fingers crossed.

Comment: It appears to be half of what I need. There are now two rows that each total 2566245. That means that there is duplication. Comparing file A with B and B with A are the same thing for my purposes.

Comment: @RSoul I update my question, can you please explain what I miss using my example?

Comment: Maybe I am confused. Thanks for clarifying. I will investigate.

Comment: I'm going to test it before accepting your answer, but I believe that you are correct and that your answer does do what I asked for. Thanks.